# Why isn't MySQL allowing access to columns with dot notation?

Tags: php, mysql

According to the [[PHP manual item on MySQL Field tables]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-table.php), I should be able to use the following syntax to access table columns with PHP 5.3 and MySQL:

```
$query = "SELECT account.*, country.* FROM account,
country WHERE country.name = 'Portugal' AND account.country_id = country.id";
```

This syntax works on the live site on which I'm trying to work locally.
However, running the same version of PHP with the syntax above on my machine throws a syntax error on the star:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*' at line 1
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the version of mySql this isn't working on:

**Server version:** 5.1.43-community

**Protocol version:** 10

Using PHP 5.3.0 on Apache 2/2.11

I appreciate the help on this.  I can't know exactly what my problem was but a few things I changed:
1.  The original server was using fastcgi while I was using apache, this i changed
2.  The original server was running non-thread safe PHP but I was, this I changed by installing a module on wamp as well as a NTS version of the same php

I wont leave as answer bc I dont know what it is

Comment: This wont solve your problem but. Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: A. You should never use `*` and 2. Backticks are your friend.

Comment: What MySQL version is this failing on? Have you inspected the `$query` variable string for things like non-printable characters?

Comment: If u need this `account.*, country.*` than y not just `*`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I cant see why that syntaxis cause error. And where you think need Backticks? Finally after `A` follow `B` :P

Comment: Uh @JuanCarlosOropeza - you count your way and I'll count mine. ;-) You're right, this syntax should not be throwing an error.Backticks are just good style that can save a myriad of headaches.

Comment: The syntaxis looks correct. The problem is somewhere else. Maybe you are pointing to wrong db.

Comment: Or have a whitespace between the period and the *

Comment: Are you sure you have both asterixes prefixed with the table name and not just one of them? I managed to get a similar error message as yours with `SELECT account.*, * FROM account,
country WHERE country.name = 'Portugal' AND account.country_id = country.id`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input everyone, I do know for sure that the database is correct because if I identify the rows in the query explicitly without using the dot notation it returns the value. The weird thing is this exact code works on a live site.  I'll retype the query in case a non printable character got inserted per Michael's suggestion.

Comment: I get no error here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84e20/1. What version of MySQL are you using on the site where it fails?

Comment: @Barmar I just posted version in edit: 5.1.43-community

Comment: PHP is irrelevant to this question, the problem is entirely in MySQL. YOu're using an old version of MySQL, you should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to retrieve all of the columns from account and country. If that's correct, you can use the following (I'm also going to use the JOIN as @Juan mentioned in his comment):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM account JOIN country ON account.country_id = country.id WHERE country.name = 'Portugal'";
```

Comment: This is not an explanation as to why the query in the OP fails. The explicit join syntax is favourable over the join condition in where, but the latter is also syntactically correct.

Answer (score -3):

Because you joined the tables you can't use the '*' wildcard to grab all the columns from each table individually. This is why MySQL threw an error.

To get the all the columns from the results of your join you can use:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM account,country WHERE country.name = 'Portugal' AND account.country_id = country.id";
```